# C#: Making falling blocks in Visual Studio Console

Tags: c#

I have a game project I am working on like 1 month in Console of Visual Studio. I just can't understand how to make blocks will fall.

Basically There is a face, moving with A and D and there are blocks and coins falling from above.
But I didn't understand how to do that. I tried a lot of things. I even tried to move blocks manually but didn't work. There was always a problem.

There is the code

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Konsol
{
    
    class Program
    {
        
        string space1 = " ";
        //Alt + 2
        string player1 = "☻";
        //Alt + 219
        string wall1 = "█";
        //Alt + 4
        string coin1 = "♦";

        int yer = 76;

        int loop = 1;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program space = new Program();
            Program player = new Program();
            Program wall = new Program();
            Program coin = new Program();

            Program[] obj = { wall, wall, wall, wall, wall, wall, wall, wall };

            bool alive = true;



            string[] e = { space.space1, player.player1, wall.wall1, coin.coin1 };

            ///////            0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8                       //////////
            string[] ana = { e[2], e[2], e[2], e[2], e[2], e[2], e[2], e[2], e[2], 

            ///////            9    1 0   1 1   1 2   1 3   1 4   1 5   1 6   1 7                    //////////
                             e[2], e[0], e[0], e[0], e[0], e[0], e[0], e[0], e[2],

            ///////           1 8   1 9   2 0   2 1   2 2   2 3   2 4   2 5   2 6                  //////////
                             e[2], e[0], e[0], e[0], e[0], e[0], e[0], e[0], e[2],

            ///////           2 7   2 8   2 9   3 0   3 1   3 2   3 3   3 4   3 5                //////////
                             e[2], e[0], e[0], e[0], e[0], e[0], e[0], e[0], e[2],

            ///////           3 6   3 7   3 8   3 9   4 0   4 1   4 2   4 3   4 4              //////////
                             e[2], e[0], e[0], e[0], e[0], e[0], e[0], e[0], e[2],

            ///////           4 5   4 6   4 7   4 8   4 9   5 0   5 1   5 2   5 3            //////////
                             e[2], e[0], e[0], e[0], e[0], e[0], e[0], e[0], e[2],

            ///////           5 4   5 5   5 6   5 7   5 8   5 9   6 0   6 1   6 2          //////////
                             e[2], e[0], e[0], e[0], e[0], e[0], e[0], e[0], e[2],

            ///////           6 3   6 4   6 5   6 6   6 7   6 8   6 9   7 0   7 1        //////////
                             e[2], e[0], e[0], e[0], e[0], e[0], e[0], e[0], e[2],

            ///////           7 2   7 3   7 4   7 5   7 6   7 7   7 8   7 9   8 0      //////////
                             e[2], e[0], e[0], e[0], e[1], e[0], e[0], e[0], e[2],

            ///////           8 1   8 2   8 3   8 4   8 5   8 6   8 7   8 8   8 9    //////////
                             e[2], e[0], e[0], e[0], e[0], e[0], e[0], e[0], e[2], };

            

        cikti:

            




            Console.Clear();

            int y = 0;

            foreach (string s in ana)
            {
                Console.Write(s);
                y++;
                if (y % 9 == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine(player.yer);

            ConsoleKeyInfo move = new ConsoleKeyInfo();
            move = Console.ReadKey(true);

            if (move.Key == ConsoleKey.A && ana[player.yer - 1] != e[2])
            {
                if (player.yer > 73) 
                {
                    player.yer--;
                }
            }

            else if (move.Key == ConsoleKey.D && ana[player.yer + 1] != e[2])
            {
                if (player.yer < 79 )
                {
                    player.yer++;
                }
            }
            
            else
            {

            }

            if (ana[player.yer - 1] == e[1] && ana[player.yer - 1] != e[2])
            {
                ana[player.yer - 1] = e[0];
                
                ana[player.yer] = e[1];
                
            }
            
            else if (ana[player.yer + 1] == e[1] && ana[player.yer + 1] != e[2])
            {
                ana[player.yer + 1] = e[0];

                ana[player.yer] = e[1];

            }
            


            Task.Run(() => Blocks(ana, e, wall, obj , coin, alive));
            


            goto cikti;       
        }

        public static void Blocks(string[] ana, string[] e, Program wall, Program[] obj , Program coin, bool alive)
        {

            Random Generator1 = new Random();
            int gen1 = Generator1.Next(1, 11);

            Random Generator2 = new Random();
            int gen2 = Generator2.Next(10, 17);

            

            
            
            switch (gen1)
            {
                    case 1:
                    case 2:
                    case 3:
                    case 4:
                    case 5:
                        break;
                    case 6:
                    case 7:
                    case 8:
                    ana[gen2] = e[2];
                        break;
                    case 9:
                    case 10:
                    ana[gen2] = e[3];
                    break;
                }
            
            
        }
    }

    
}
```

Please help me.

There are a few thing I tried before but I didn't delete it so ignore they.

Comment: No offense intended, but your code is _hugely_ overcomplicated because there are elemental C# concepts you do not yet grasp. I strongly suggest that you actually pick up a basic C# tutorial because an answer here cannot teach you everything that is missing from your code.

Comment: I can't find a good C# tutorial actualy.
I know basics, some complitent ones but still can't find a good tutorial to make something. I check microsoft tutorials, some apps etc. Thanks for replies..

Comment: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/learn/csharp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what exactly you're trying to do and I don't think a console app is the right place to do it. On top of that it doesn't look like you have a lot of programming experience so maybe **try to learn the basics first**.

But this still looked like a fun challenge so I gave it a try:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Create new thread in order to not block main tread
        Thread BlockFallingThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(FallingBlocks));
        BlockFallingThread.Start();
    }

    private static void FallingBlocks()
    {
        //List of symbols (O is your Block)
        List<string> symbols = new List<string>() { " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "O" };

        //Endless loop of falling blocks
        while (true)
        {
            //Output all symbols from list except the last one
            for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" " + symbols[i]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("___");

            //Wait 0,1sec
            Thread.Sleep(100); //adjust this number to change the time which the block takes to fall down

            //Move the last symbol from list to the front
            symbols.Insert(0, symbols[7]);
            symbols.RemoveAt(8);

            //Clear console and repeat loop
            Console.Clear();
        }
    }
```

If you want to try this code out don't forget to add this at the top:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
```

Comment: Thanks for answering... This can help. Thank you for advices too...